# How to concat two string with addon word to the column value in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I am trying to concat two columns with concat and concat_ws function. Along with concatinating two columns I also want to append a word to this concatination. So I tried to achieve that using below method

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT("SRID=4326;POINT(", CONCAT_WS(" ",cast(A.longitude as string),cast(A.latitude as string))), ")") as the_geom 
FROM test
```

With above syntax I am getting the following error.

```
**org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:13 cannot recognize input near 'CONCAT' '(' 'CONCAT' in expression specification**
```

I was not knowing what wrong I am doing in the above syntax. Is there any alternative way to achieve this.

**Expected RESULT :** `SRID=4326;POINT(127.155104 35.8091378)`

I tried all ways using concat and concat_ws, but getting syntax issues.

Comment: One of Concat expected. SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT("SRID=4326;POINT(", CONCAT_WS(" ",cast(A.longitude as string),cast(A.latitude as string))), ")") as the_geom 
FROM test

Comment: Thank you for your response. After adding one more concat also I am getting same error i.e,.       org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:13 cannot recognize input near 'CONCAT' '(' 'CONCAT' in expression specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is semicolon, it breaks the query. Try replacing semicolon with `\073`, also double backslash may work `\\;`

Also it seems single concat is enough.

Demo using `\073` :

```
with test as (
select 12134.12345 as longitude, 12134.12345 as latitude
)

SELECT CONCAT("SRID=4326\073POINT(", 
               CONCAT_WS(" ",cast(A.longitude as string),cast(A.latitude as string))
               , ")"
             ) as the_geom 
FROM test A
```

Result:

```
SRID=4326;POINT(12134.12345 12134.12345)
```

Comment: leftjoin,  Thank you :-)  yes semicolon was the problem. 
1. With your solution for semicolon I am able to get the desired output.
2. Only \073 was working for semicolon. 
3. When I tried with \\; then also it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @Jayasree In some tools `\\;` works well. Tested in Qubole GUI

Comment: That might be the reason then. Got to know now.

Comment: When  I am using \073 in simple select statement then it is working, but while I am using this select statement in while inserting data into new table using INSERT statement then \073 is coming as 073 only. Can i know like why is this happening ? and how to overcome with that bug ? @leftjoin

Comment: To make semi-colon work with INSERT statement, we should specify semicolon as \u003B along with concat. It worked for me.